# How can I share a Microsoft OneNote note/section/notebook between a list of emails using OneNote API, Office 365 API or OneDrive API in a MVC website?

Tags: onedrive, office365api, onenote-api

I need to be able to create OneNote notes/sections/notebooks and to share them between a certain list of users from a Asp .NET MVC website. How could I do that?

Comment: You'll improve your odds of getting help if you can show an attempt and explain where you're having trouble.

Comment: After spending some time in searching for  support for sharing in the API, I came to a dead end. For now the OneNote API offers support for creating, updating notes, but no sharing yet. Now I'm starting to consider other solutions.

Answer (score -1):

We can use OneNote API to manipulate the content of OneNote. Then we need to share the OneNote with users manually. For example, we can get a link then share the link in the MVC web site.

Answer (score -1):

This is possible using the ONEDRIVE API.

You can create a sharing link for a sharepoint item with a POST request as described at https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/api/item_createlink

For example:

POST /drive/root:/{item-path}:/microsoft.graph.createLink
Content-type: application/json

```
{
    "type": "view",
    "scope": "anonymous"
}
```

will create a guest link to the OneNote notebook with read access.

You have to enable this in Sharepoint admin centre as per this link:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-external-sharing-for-your-SharePoint-Online-environment-c8a462eb-0723-4b0b-8d0a-70feafe4be85?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US